# Run a macro when a PivotTable is inserted from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, pivot-table

I would like an Excel macro to run automatically when a PivotTable is inserted from a MySQL Database using the MySQL for Excel add-in.

The PivotTable is inserted into a sheet that already exists, and takes up the range A2:CN600, depending on how many rows the table has. I have the following code, which works perfectly when one cell in the specified range is altered:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("A2:CN600")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then


        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    End If
End Sub
```

Experimentally, I inserted the MySQL database as a PivotTable into this sheet to see what would happen, however no message box popped up. When I hit Ctrl+a and Delete to remove the table, I got the message:

> Cell $A$2:$CN$600 has changed.

How can I modify this code so that it will display the message box when the table is inserted? I understand the above code is more suited to a case where the cell values are changed one at a time, instead of a large range having their value changed all at once.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel

Answer (score 1):

Pivot tables are a bit different - thus for them there are other events. Try this event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
     MsgBox Target.TableRange1.Address
End Sub
```

Take a look at the other PivotTable related events:

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly if I insert a new PivotTable, however when I insert the PivotTable using the MySQL add-in, it doesn't call the macro. Any idea why?

Comment: Probably the `AddIn` is disabling the events temporarily. Idk.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel

Comment: @peakpeak - what is the idea of the link?